# Sugestions for fixing a read.csv

Tags: r, date, read.csv

I am reading a csv file,

```
data <- read.csv("F:/Root/ PUMPING - data.csv", header = T, sep = ";")
```

which is a dataframe of 1168 observation with 8 variables.

The variables and the table look like this:

```
  Fiscal_Year SiteState      county  StartDate    EndDate Site_Type Count_Site Sum_Gallons
1        FY 18        IA      Butler 21/11/2017 21/11/2017         F          3      554700
2        FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 18/10/2017 19/10/2017         F          1     1124085
3        FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 19/10/2017 19/10/2017         F          1      478240
4        FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 20/10/2017 20/10/2017         F          1      201306
5        FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 20/10/2017 21/10/2017         F          1      973760
6        FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 20/10/2017 23/10/2017         F          1      784743
7        FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 26/10/2017 26/10/2017         F          1      246462
8        FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 27/10/2017 29/10/2017         F          1      561808
9        FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 30/10/2017 30/10/2017         F          1      519946
10       FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 02/11/2017 02/11/2017         F          2      816240
11       FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 03/11/2017 08/11/2017         F          1     1260160
12       FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 04/11/2017 04/11/2017         F          2      757145
13       FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 05/11/2017 05/11/2017         F          3     1022532
14       FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 06/11/2017 06/11/2017         F          1      565500
15       FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 06/11/2017 07/11/2017         F          1      682500
16       FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 07/11/2017 07/11/2017         F          3      905442
17       FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 08/11/2017 08/11/2017         F          1      128880
18       FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 09/11/2017 09/11/2017         F          2      509776
19       FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 10/11/2017 11/11/2017         F          1      730916
20       FY 18        IA Cerro Gordo 12/11/2017 12/11/2017         F          1      440577
```

I have encontered several problems when working with the dates columns.
When I apply the nrow() command, this is what I see:

```
> nrow(data)
[1] 1168
```

but for each variable (for example):

```
> nrow(data$Fiscal_Year)
NULL
> nrow(data$SiteState)
NULL
```

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to fix this and import all the data into rows? I am not trying to count the objects in the vectors. Several problems arise later from this structure. I believe that those will be fixed if the values where in the rows.

Comment: I do not understand what "I believe that those will be fixed if the values where in the rows." Which values are missing in which rows? It has been pointed out already that you can't use `nrow` for vectors like in `nrow(data$Fiscal_Year)`.

Comment: >When I want to do some other processes, as per example: dates <- data_clean$StartDate + 1:data_clean$ndays, I have the following message
numerical expression has 1115 elements: only the first used

Comment: Yes, the issue is with your code and not with the data. On the right-hand site of `:` can be only one single value. You are putting 1115 values there. You can reproduce the issue with `1:c(1,2)`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because output of `data$Fiscal_Year` is a vector, and vectors don't have rows for R to count, vectors are one dimentional objects. You need to use `length(data$Fiscal_Year)`

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not explained my self well. I am not trying to count the objects inside the vector. The way that this structure is laid out is causing problems with some formulas later. I think having the data where each value is in one row will fix all the other problems.

Comment: If you think you need the data to be in a different format, can you mention the same in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It probably makes sense to revisit the later code and fix it so that it can handle vectors as input, but you can preserve the structure of a data frame column if you need to by using `nrow(data[, "Fiscal_Year", drop=FALSE])`. Here's an example with the `iris` data set that comes with R:

```
data(iris)
str(iris)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... nrow(iris)
# [1] 150
nrow(iris$Sepal.Length)
# NULL
nrow(iris[, "Sepal.Length"])
# NULL
nrow(iris[, "Sepal.Length", drop=FALSE])
# [1] 150 
head(iris$Sepal.Length)
[1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4
head(iris[, "Sepal.Length", drop=FALSE])
#   Sepal.Length
# 1          5.1
# 2          4.9
# 3          4.7
# 4          4.6
# 5          5.0
# 6          5.4
```